# switching my google account

Tags: gmail, accounts

so I have two Gmail accounts. I made one of them my account on my cell phone and then now, a year later, I switched to my other account. has anything happened? anything changed? and also, why do I need to be signed in with a google account in the first place? to get apps?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing will be affected. when you login to.Your account your Google account gets synced and gets its self updated and yeah definitely you will be having large number of unread e-mails.You can also have multiple Google accounts running at the same time.